# going from php scan output of nested folder to proper html list tags

Tags: php, html, list, menu

Based on previous Q&A on this site, I have nearly reached my goal of a *php function that creates/updates a navigation menu in HTML from a filesystem folder*. I am stuck on rendering the html properly for a menu.

**Folder "stuff" and its structure:**

`├── A
│   └── a
└── B
    ├── b
    └── BB
        ├── bb
        └── BBB
            └── bbb`

** php function:**

```
<?php
function makelist($path) {
$dir   = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path,         
RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, 
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($files as $file) {
$nameonly=basename($file);
$indent = str_repeat('   ', $files->getDepth());
echo $indent, "<a href=$file>$nameonly<a>\n";
}
}
makelist('stuff');
```

I am very close to what I need here. The directory is properly traversed and I have nearly the right links albeit not quite alphabetical:

```
<a href=stuff/B>B<a>
  <a href=stuff/B/BB>BB<a>
    <a href=stuff/B/BB/bb>bb<a>
    <a href=stuff/B/BB/BBB>BBB<a>
        <a href=stuff/B/BB/BBB/bbb>bbb<a>
  <a href=stuff/B/b>b<a>
<a href=stuff/A>A<a>
  <a href=stuff/A/a>a<a>
```

***My question***

I have not figured out how I could wrap the returned result in the proper `<ul><li>`. Is it feasible with the current function that I have? I have no problem tossing it if there is a better way that renders the folder structure and its links in html.

Thank you in advance

PS: All the atomic parts of my question have been repeatedly asked on StackOverflow, but I am stuck at the molecular level and I have searched and searched to find this solution.

Comment: You should try defining your function recusrively. Recursive solutions, while slower, are more readable and easier to maintain. You can just print out a <ul></ul> at the beggining/end of each of the function's recursions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone finds it useful, this version worked as needed:

```
function ListMaker($root, $host = null): string
{
    $out = '';
    $dirs = array_diff(scandir($root), ['..', '.']);
    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
        $path = $root . '/' . $dir;
        $link = $host . $path;
        if (is_file($path)) {
            $out .= '<li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$path.'</a>';
        }
        if (is_dir($path)) {
            $out .= '<li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$dir.'</a>';
            $out .= "<ul>" .ListMaker($path, $host) . "</ul>";
            $out .= "</li>";
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Here I haven't tested this, but this is the jist of what you need:

```
<?php 
function recursive_menu_structure($directory){
    $files = scandir($directory);

    if(count($files) > 0){
        echo "<ul>\n";

        foreach($files as $file){
            if(is_dir($file)){
                recursive_menu_structure($directory . '/' . $file);
            }
            else{
                 echo "<li><a href='$file'></a></li>\n";
            }            

        }

        echo "</ul>\n";
    }


}
?>
```